# How to quickly clear thousands of CS0234 errors in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, cs0246

This is a shared project that was working for me until today. It still compiles without errors in our CI system and for all of my teammates, but my computer started getting more than 3000 CS0234 errors when I compile this solution.

I tried cleaning the solution, I manually deleted the bin and obj folders, I deleted the packages folder and got all the NuGet packages again from the package source, I even rebooted my machine. Nothing helps.

These are not real errors, if I double click an error message, the source file opens initially with red ink, but this quickly disappears, then the error is removed from the error list.

I can fix my problem by simply double clicking each error and waiting a few seconds, but there are over 3000 error messages. My question is, is there a faster way to get Visual Studio back in sync. Since this only affects my machine there must be some kind of cache somewhere that's broken and if I could find it and delete it, maybe this situation would be resolved quickly.

Comment: Possibly NUGET packages are not up-to-date?  Perhaps the build-order is not correct?

Comment: This doesn’t explain why our CI system can build the solution without errors, so can everyone else on my team, and I was able to build the same solution yesterday. It also doesn’t explain why simply opening the source code file fixes the errors for that file. I think some kind of internal caching of information that is updated when the source code file is opened seems much more likely to me.